# CSS min-height not working

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have two pages on my website. On this page min-height is working:

http://isometricland.net/home.php

On this page it is not:

http://isometricland.net/blog/?cat=4

It's a mystery to me why this is the case since structurally they should be nearly identical. Can I get some help determining why? Thanks.

Comment: Please brief that where you applied min-height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the link `http://isometricland.net/blog/?cat=4` at the following section:

```
<!-- START MIDDLE PANE -->
```

Change the style `position` to `absolute` **instead of** `relative`:

```
<div style="position: absolute;..."
```